# python with SQL (NEWBIE WARNING)

Tags: python, sql

```
counter=cur.rowcount
if(counter !=0):
    values =[]
    x=0
    for row in content:
        dValue,  dYearOf, dMonthOf, Department = row
        sent = str(dValue)
        x=x+1
        q=0
        NounNum = 0

        for noun in Noun:

            AdjectiveNum=0
            if " "+noun+" " in sent:

                for adjective in Adjective:
                    AdjectiveNum=AdjectiveNum+1

                    if " "+adjective+" " in dValue:

                        sup=[]

                        for support in Support:

                            if " "+support+" " in sent:
                                sup=sup+[support]

                        supp = '-'.join(map(str, sup))
                        values.append(x.to_bytes)
                        values.append(noun)
                        values.append(NA[NounNum])
                        values.append(adjective)
                        values.append(supp)
                        values.append(dMonthOf)
                        values.append(dYearOf)
                        values.append(Department[:2])


f_value= ','.join(map(str, values))
sql=("""NSERT INTO `text_mining`(`Count`, `Noun`, `Noun_Code`, `Support`, `Adjective`, `Month`, `Year`, `Division`) VALUES (%s)""")
print(sql,f_value)
cur.execute(sql,f_value)
```

how can I put the an array value in my insert query?  i tried some ways but I am trying to make an string that will combine all of my variable into 1 including with my array. obviously i am new with this so please help

Comment: From your comments, it sounds like you are looking for the .join() command. Could you provide a short example of sample inputs as well as the desired output you are looking for?

Comment: i tried the .join() instead it replace 1 of my variable as <built-in method to_bytes of int object at 0x6FD3D760>,
i want my output like this
('NSERT INTO `text_mining`(`Count`, `Noun`, `Noun_Code`, `Support`, `Adjective`, `Month`, `Year`, `Division`) VALUES (%s)', [4, 'pharmacy', 'A1', 'kulang', '', 9, 2017, 'PD', 8, 'service', 'A1', 'tagal', '', 9, 2017, 'PD', 10, 'gamot', 'A1', 'agad', '', 9, 2017, 'PD', 17, 'room', 'A1', 'mabilis', '', 9, 2017, 'PD')

Comment: Well, if your keys will always be the same (i.e. 'Count', 'Noun', 'Noun_Code', etc.), then you might think about creating a dictionary with these as your keys and then construct arrays that serve as the list of values for each of those keys.

Comment: When adding details to your question, put it in the question.  Look at the code you added in the comment.  It is much harder to read than when it is properly formatted in the question.

Comment: Sorry i am new to this hehe